# How to Iterate List of QueryDSl object referred from another QueryDSL object during applying filter to query

Tags: querydsl

I have two entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

............
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
private ArrayList<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>();

...getter..setters'
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
 {
...............
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "m_employee_department",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_id",     referencedColumnName = "department_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id"))
private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
```

I am using QueryDsl over JPA . In UI I want to search all Employees with filter as department . Where Employee and Department are in relationship many to many. For that reason I want to apply filter in my QueryDsl query
something like

```
QDepartment department = QDepartment.department;
QEmployee employee = QEmployee.employee;
if (departments != null && departments.size() > 0) {
            BooleanExpression booleanExpression = null;
            for (int count = 1; count < categories.size(); count++) {
                booleanExpression = booleanExpression.or(
                        employee.departments._____(department.get(count)));
            }
            builder.and(booleanExpression);
        }
```

but the problem is employee.department returns a SimplePath> and I want to iterate this so that I can match the employee.departments ids with department.id(getting from UI)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
QEmployee employee = QEmployee.employee;
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
if (departments != null) {
    for (Department dep : departments) {
        builder.or(employee.departments.any().eq(dep)); 
    }
}

query.where(builder)...
```